# Randomly repeating key

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

My computer will randomly start repeating keys. At first it was the ≥ key, which led me to believe it was more than just a stuck key since that is an option-key character and the chances that they would stick at the same time was slim.

It has now started doing it with the / key. It happens randomly and starts and stops randomly as well. Restarting it isn't a surefire solution, although restarting, resetting the SMC and zapping the PRAM usually fixes it. I have tried reinstalling Mountain Lion.

What else should/is there to do to try to fix this problem?

Comment: It could potentially be a hardware issue. Can you run Hardware Diagnostics? If it's a newer model (1-3 years old or so), try booting holding down cmd-R.

Comment: For newer models this is documented at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8536157

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a hardware issue and recommend taking it to an Apple service center.

This happened to me once on a Dell laptop. Our IT department replaced the keyboard and that fixed it.

To diagnose I determined it wasn't a software issue by noticing the key could repeat before the operating system had loaded. If you are dual booting Windows you could use the same technique to determine if it is a software or hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

Take it into your nearest Apple Store to get its hardware looked at properly. You seem to have ruled out potential software issues.